# Python scan for network IP addresses and macs

Tags: python, linux, lan

[ip a output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zp045.png) [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIa5X.png)I am trying to create a script that scans a LAN and obtains the ip address and mac address of all the machines using Python. The script below does this, however it prints the list twice? How could this be achieved, or how could the script below be changed to print the list once(as a dictionary where the ip address is the key and the mac is the value)?

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
import logging
import scapy.config
import scapy.layers.l2
import scapy.route
import socket
import math
import errno

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-5s %(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def long2net(arg):
    if (arg <= 0 or arg >= 0xFFFFFFFF):
        raise ValueError("illegal netmask value", hex(arg))
    return 32 - int(round(math.log(0xFFFFFFFF - arg, 2)))


def to_CIDR_notation(bytes_network, bytes_netmask):
    network = scapy.utils.ltoa(bytes_network)
    netmask = long2net(bytes_netmask)
    net = "%s/%s" % (network, netmask)
    if netmask < 16:
        logger.warn("%s is too big. skipping" % net)
        return None

    return net


def scan_and_print_neighbors(net, interface, timeout=1):
    logger.info("arping %s on %s" % (net, interface))
    try:
        ans, unans = scapy.layers.l2.arping(net, iface=interface, timeout=timeout, verbose=True)
        for s, r in ans.res:
            line = r.sprintf("%Ether.src%  %ARP.psrc%")
            try:
                hostname = socket.gethostbyaddr(r.psrc)
                line += " " + hostname[0]
            except socket.herror:
                # failed to resolve
                pass
            logger.info(line)
    except socket.error as e:
        if e.errno == errno.EPERM:     # Operation not permitted
            logger.error("%s. Did you run as root?", e.strerror)
        else:
            raise


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for network, netmask, _, interface, address in scapy.config.conf.route.routes:

        # skip loopback network and default gw
        if network == 0 or interface == 'lo' or address == '127.0.0.1' or address == '0.0.0.0':
            continue

        if netmask <= 0 or netmask == 0xFFFFFFFF:
            continue

        net = to_CIDR_notation(network, netmask)

        if interface != scapy.config.conf.iface:
            # see http://trac.secdev.org/scapy/ticket/537
            logger.warn("skipping %s because scapy currently doesn't support arping on non-primary network interfaces", net)
            continue

        if net:
            scan_and_print_neighbors(net, interface)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting `verbose` to `False`?

```
ans, unans = scapy.layers.l2.arping(net, iface=interface, timeout=timeout, verbose=False)
```

In addition to setting `verbose=False` in your `scapy.layers.l2.arping(`,
import the `conf` module:

```
from scapy.all import conf
```

And add `conf.verb=0` just below your `if __name__ == "__main__":` line:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    conf.verb=0
    for network, netmask, _, interface, address in scapy.config.conf.route.routes:

        # skip loopback network and default gw
        if network == 0 or interface == 'lo' or address == '127.0.0.1' or address == '0.0.0.0':
            continue
```

**EDIT:** I think your script is looping once for each "route" defined in your `/proc/net/route` that hasn't already been explicitly filtered out (i.e. the lines above your `continue` commands.)  My guess is that if you where to execute `route -n` you'll probably find 2 routes in there that somehow have the same Network and Interface values but something else is differing like Netmask or Gateway.

Anyways, the hackish way to get pass this is to add a `break` after your call to `scan_and_print_neighbors(net, interface)` to exit the for-loop.

For example:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    for network, netmask, _, interface, address in scapy.config.conf.route.routes:

        # skip loopback network and default gw
        if network == 0 or interface == 'lo' or address == '127.0.0.1' or address == '0.0.0.0':
            continue

        if netmask <= 0 or netmask == 0xFFFFFFFF:
            continue

        net = to_CIDR_notation(network, netmask)

        if interface != scapy.config.conf.iface:
            # see http://trac.secdev.org/scapy/ticket/537
            logger.warn("skipping %s because scapy currently doesn't support arping on non-primary network interfaces", net)
            continue

        if net:
            scan_and_print_neighbors(net, interface)
            break
```

Comment: Yes i have, it still prints a list twice?

Comment: Updated my answer and tested on my system. Now it only prints the info you declared with logger, not the verbose info coming from the scapy module itself.

Comment: it still prints out two lists. What did you mean by import the conf module inside scapy.layers.l2.arping?

Comment: Can you add to your question a snippet of your results and also an example of the expected behaviour?

Comment: i added a screenshot of the output, as you can see it scans the LAN twice. i need it to print out just once

Comment: How many network interfaces do you have? Can you post the output of `ip a` command?